# Comparing chars one by one in a character array with strcmp

Tags: c++, strcmp

I'm writing a c++ script that compare chars of two strings one by one using strcmp().
I wrote this code:

```
        char test1[1];
        char test2[1];
        test1[0]=str1[i];  //str1 is a char array
        test2[0]=str2[i];  //str2 is a char array
        int result=strcmp(test1,test2);
```

but if I print test1 or test2 I encountered with two chars.
for example if first index of str1='a' then test1 is "aa" but I don't know why?
Please Help.

Comment: `strcmp()` requires a C-style null-terminated string. `test1[1]` doesn't have room for a character and the terminator.

Comment: `strcmp` is for comparing NUL terminated C-strings not individual characters. To compare characters just use `==` like `str1[i] == str2[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp()` takes **null-terminated** strings, but neither of your `char[]` arrays are null-terminated.

```c
char test1[2]; // <-- increase this!
char test2[2]; // <-- increase this!
test1[0] = str1[i];
test1[1] = '\0'; // <-- add this!
test2[0] = str2[i];
test2[1] = '\0'; // <-- add this!
int result = strcmp(test1, test2);
```

Otherwise, you can use `strncmp()` instead, which does not require null terminators, so no `char[]` arrays are needed, eg:

```c
char test1 = str1[i];
char test2 = str2[i];
int result = strncmp(&test1, &test2, 1);
```

Or simply:

```c
int result = strncmp(&str1[i], &str2[i], 1);
// or:
// int result = strncmp(str1+i, str2+i, 1);
```